# How do you stop Idea 14 from comingling base methods within extended classes in the UI?

Tags: grails, user-interface, intellij-idea

In IDEA 14 how do you stop base methods from showing up in the UI for an extended class?

As you can see in the image below (grails project) I have extended the Register Controller.  While my class only has a register and verifyRegistration method, the UI lists all of the methods of the base class.  If I double-click on one of the other methods (for example: forgotPassword) IDEA will open that method in the base class (in this case by opening the groovy file contained in the spring-security-ui plugin).  Unless you are *very* careful you are likely to inadvertently edit the base method (ex: register) rather than your extended version.

Is there some way to stop IDEA from doing this?  Ideally I should only see the actual methods (register, verifyRegistration) in the tree view to the left.

Thanks,

[image: Intellij IDEA 14 extended class]